# Reading/making a backup of a text file

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have the following code that is attempting to read a text file, make a backup, and pass the read file string on to further processing routines. The behaviour I am seeing is very unexpected.

```
01: rewind(PPLFile);
02: fseek(PPLFile, 0, SEEK_END);
03: unsigned long fsize = ftell(PPLFile);
04: char *string = (char*)calloc(fsize + 1, sizeof(char));
05: rewind(PPLFile);
06: fread(string, sizeof(char), fsize, PPLFile);

07: FILE* PPLBackup;
08: char* fileSuffix = ".backup";
09: char* PPLBackupLocation = (char*)calloc(strlen(basePath) + strlen(fileSuffix) + 1, sizeof(char));
10: strcpy(PPLBackupLocation, basePath);
11: strcat(PPLBackupLocation, fileSuffix);
12: PPLBackup = fopen(PPLBackupLocation, "w");
13: fprintf(PPLBackup, fileContent);
14: fclose(PPLBackup);
15: free(PPLBackupLocation);
```

The file handle `*PPLFile` has been opened previously with the `w+` or `a+` flag depending on certain cases in the previous code that wrote the file initially.

The concept I thought was quite simple:

1. Move the pointer past the end of the file and sense its location to establish file size in bytes
2. Create null string of the byte size plus one (for the null terminator)
3. Rewind and read the whole file content into the string, up to the sensed file size
4. Create backup file name and file pointer
5. Write the whole string read from the original file to the new backup file.
6. Close the backup file and continue by processing the read string

There are a two disturbing symptoms:

1. The *char string containing the original file has many more zeroes (thousands in a text file ~=20MB), so the last non-zero value might be 3000 bytes from the end. Seemingly smaller than the original file.
2. When writing the backup file, the resulting file is a small amount *larger* than the original file, with a seemingly random extra sample of the original file attached to the end, again a few thousand bytes.

Quite simply, what on earth is going on?

Comment: Why not collect the string content while writing instead of rewind/ftell/fseek and just write it to the bakup file when finished?

Comment: @A4L that is done for efficiency. The writing is a high-frequency logger for a real-time system, the code I am adding is essentially post-processing.

Comment: Ok, was just curious to know ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This row not good:

```
13: fprintf(PPLBackup, fileContent);
```

If the file contains character sequences like `%s` then `fprintf` will look for additional data on the stack.

You should use `fwrite` instead:

```
13: fwrite(fileContent, fsize, 1, PPLBackup);
```

or at least do this:

```
13: fprintf(PPLBackup, "%s", fileContent);
```

Comment: Thanks Klas, I tried using fwrite, the results still don't make so much sense. With an original file size of 3,801,868b (reported by Windows), I can confirm that same value coming from the fseek() such that fsize is the same. The resulting file from fwrite() I can now hex edit to see the zeroes from the initial read, but it is still now 1002b too long, Windows reporting 3,802,870b for the new file.
The original read (stored in `string` is 780b short, with only zeroes following.

Comment: Curious, the original file has 1002 lines.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode. Otherwise you will get newline conversions. That goes for both reading and writing.

Comment: Newline conversions seemed to be my exact problem, one per line. Specifically it seems the \r character seems to be ignored when reading bytes from a file opened in text mode. (Or possibly more accurately, \n\r combinations are interpreted as \n characters.
The writing is a little more confusing, since there are no '%' characters in the original file and I would therefore expect the written file to be short by the same amount by finding the first null terminator before the end of the array. It wasn't. Nonetheless opening in binary and writing using fwrite() was the answer.

Comment: An output file in text mode, in a PC, will convert a `"\n"` to `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you reading with fread() and writing with fprintf() instead of fwrite()? And the way you're using fprintf(), you're at the mercy of the first `%` sign in the file (format string vulnerability).

Also, make sure both files are open in the same mode (text mode vs. binary mode). Usually, fread()/fwrite() tend to be used with binary mode.

Comment: I collated the above code for readability here. The backup code (07-15 above) is in a subroutine and maybe only for pedantry I try to minimise the size of function signatures. In this case I wanted to eliminate the need for passing `fsize`. I will certainly try this now though.

Answer (score 0):

This complete program works for me on Linux.  It has the alteration by Klas.  Note I had to use fsize as a global because passing around the char * contents of the file to be copied broke if it was later strlen'd - for obvious reasons

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long fsize=0L;

char *get_file(FILE *PPLFile) {
    rewind(PPLFile);
    fseek(PPLFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(PPLFile);
    char *string = (char*)calloc(fsize + 1, sizeof(char));
    rewind(PPLFile);
    fread(string, sizeof(char), fsize, PPLFile);
    return string;
}

void write_file(char *basePath, char *fileContent) {
 FILE* PPLBackup;
 char* fileSuffix = ".backup";
 char* PPLBackupLocation = (char*)calloc(strlen(basePath) + strlen(fileSuffix) + 1, sizeof(char));
 strcpy(PPLBackupLocation, basePath);
 strcat(PPLBackupLocation, fileSuffix);
 PPLBackup = fopen(PPLBackupLocation, "w");
 fwrite(fileContent, fsize, 1, PPLBackup);
 fclose(PPLBackup);
 free(PPLBackupLocation);
}
```

Comment: Using "wb" in Linux is OK and makes the code more portable.  Same goes for "rb" on the read side.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues

1. As mentioned by @Klas Lindbäck & @Medinoc, do not use `fprintf()`.  `fwrite()` is much better.
2. @Klas Lindbäck says, insure that you open *both* the file read and write in *binary* mode. as in `fopen(PPLBackupLocation, "wb")`.
3. The return value from `fread()` should be assessed and if good, used for your `fwrite()`.
4. `calloc(fsize + 1, sizeof(char))` does not need to add 1.